# Smart power supply?

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I have a 12 V, 10 amp invention for emergencies that must run for hours at a time and run without interruption. Sometimes it is close to a house and can use an AC extension cord but usually it is far from a home and must run from a 12 v 100 Ah battery.

I would like to accomplish these three scenarios with one configuration:

1. Battery is missing. An extension cord is plugged in for a built-in power supply that supplies 12 V 10 A power supply.
2. There is a battery but it became discharged. The extension cord is plugged in and must power a built-in trickle charge and the circuitry must also simultaneously power the 12 V 10 A device.
3. The battery is fully charged, no extension cord is required (for a while at least). The device is powered directly by the battery.

I tried using a trickle charge for option 1 but apparently the new ones are too smart and it must sense a battery attached to even power on. I understand a power supply should not be used to charge a battery.
Is there some circuit design that can accomplish all three scenarios above automatically without the customer having to push any buttons?

Comment: Google uninterruptible power supply (or UPS) and see if that meets your needs.

Comment: A trickle charger won't be able to supply 15A for scenario 1.

Comment: If the battery is discharged you'll need more than a trickle to charge it back up. You need to decide how long that should take.

Comment: To clarify, this device is for outdoors. It may be close enough to a house that an extension cord can reach. But I'd like the option to have a 12 v 100 Ah battery run it without any extension cord.

Answer (score 1):

> 12 V 15 A

vs

> I may have a 12v 150mAh battery

by the very simple definition of what "mAh" is, namely "mA for hours", you can directly see that this battery would power the device for 1/100 hours = 36 seconds, *at most*, if it actually draws 15 A. (And batteries with capacities this small are usually not optimized for a current this high, so chances are you get far less runtime at a useful voltage, if any.)

So, check whether this is useful for your use case at all.

> Can all three options be accomplished automatically with one device and without the customer remembering to toggle any switches?

Exactly how any consumer device with a rechargable battery works, be it a laptop, a phone or an electric razor. Yes, that's possible, with any of the literally thousands of battery charger designs that you can buy.

Comment: It's a 100th hour. And another question is whether such a small battery can supply 15 A at all without too much droop.

Comment: uff, numbers be hard; @tobalt: I fixed that.

Comment: Yikes, I said "mAh" when I meant "Ah".  I'm using a standard a large marine deep cycle battery: 12v with 150 Ah capacity.  Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Ah, OK, so that's 10 hrs of runtime. But still, this really doesn't change the answer :)